# Vectorize list of lists uisng countvectorizer() & tfidfvectorizer()

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

So I have the following list of lists which is tokenized:

```
tokenized_list = [['ALL', 'MY', 'CATS', 'IN', 'A', 'ROW'], ['WHEN', 'MY', 
                   'CAT', 'SITS', 'DOWN', ',', 'SHE', 'LOOKS', 'LIKE', 'A', 
                   'FURBY', 'TOY', '!'], ['THE', CAT', 'FROM', 'OUTER', 
                   'SPACE'], ['SUNSHINE', 'LOVES', 'TO', 'SIT', 
                   'LIKE', 'THIS', 'FOR', 'SOME', 'REASON', '.']]
```

When i try to vectorize it using the CountVectorizer() or TfIdfVectorizer()

```
 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
 vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
 print(vectorizer.fit_transform(tokenized_list).todense()) 
 print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

And if I put a **simple list** inside the **vectorizer.fit_transform()** function it works properly.

How do I remove this error?

Comment: you want to flatten the list.

Comment: I just want to use the count vectorizer function in the process of building a bag of words model in nlp. What do you mean by flatten ? Sorry, new to this.

Comment: Read the linked duplicate.

Comment: You can just convert the inner list to string by using `tokenized_list = [' '.join(inner_list) for inner_list in tokenized_list]`

Comment: Hi Vivek! Thanks! I got the desired result.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga IMO this is not a duplicate of the question specified. Flattening the posted list as it is actually gives a wrong result. `@Vivek Kumar`'s comment solves the question by joining the inner lists to strings. Would you reconsider the flag?

Answer (score 1):

`tokenized_list` is a list of lists. Trying iterating the list and passing the sublist as argument or you can flatten the list.

**Ex:**

```
tokenized_list = [['ALL', 'MY', 'CATS', 'IN', 'A', 'ROW'], ['WHEN', 'MY', 
                   'CAT', 'SITS', 'DOWN', ',', 'SHE', 'LOOKS', 'LIKE', 'A', 
                   'FURBY', 'TOY', '!'], ['THE', 'CAT', 'FROM', 'OUTER', 
                   'SPACE'], ['SUNSHINE', 'LOVES', 'TO', 'SIT', 
                   'LIKE', 'THIS', 'FOR', 'SOME', 'REASON', '.']]

from itertools import chain
tokenized_list = list(chain(*tokenized_list))
print(vectorizer.fit_transform(tokenized_list).todense())
```

**Output:**

```
[[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: This re-fits the data each iteration, almost certainly not what is desired.

Comment: For your earlier answer - it was giving me the same error as before.

Comment: I need to get this for each unique value, for eg in this corpus there are 26 unique variables, so i should be getting 26 lists. Not more than that.

Comment: You have 34 elements so you are getting 34 lists

Comment: @Rakesh Thanks i got what i desired from the above solution.